# How to populate variable to all view logged user

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7, user-variables

I have code like bellow:

```
return view('Dashboard.AccountSettingsView', [
    'PageTitle' => config('app.name', 'Laravel') . ' | ' . __('Profile'),
    'PageHeader' => __('Profile'),
    'user' => Auth::user()
]);
```

How i can pass $user variable to all login user view, so i don't need to create 'user' => Auth::user() in every controller.

Thank you

Comment: This section of the docs shows how: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: have you solved the problem? I would recommend you use https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

Comment: @DigitalDrifter it will work if it like this `$userData = 'Test String';`, but it won't work if it like this`$userData = Auth::user();`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter when i try `dd($userData);` it give me `null` message

Comment: @AndySong seems to complicate with view composer, but i will try

Comment: @AndySong thanks, it work with composer, and it very easy >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's easy, what you can do is that add `*` for all the views. And add a check in case there is no login user.

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', function ($view) {
           if (Auth::check()) {
            $view->with('user', Auth::user());
             }
        });
    }
```

Comment: if use `Auth:check()`, it will show error $user is undefined

Comment: @IHarrisMarfel in you blade file?

Comment: @IHarrisMarfel you need  to do some check anyways, otherwise the the `$user` will be null. and when you access the some properties in you blade you will get an error as well.

Comment: `if (Auth::check()) {
 View::composer('*', function ($view) {
  $view->with('user', Auth::user());
});` show undifine, but with 
`View::composer('*', function ($view) {
 if ( Auth::check() ){
  $view->with('user', Auth::user());
 }
});` it run perfect